# What is the correct way to run use threads in Qt for that can perform a blocking task?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, sdl, qthread

I am making a media player app in Qt with C++. There will be a list of audio files and when the user clicks on an item it will start playing. If the user clicks another item while one is already playing the currently playing item will stop and the new one will start. If the whole file is finished playing then the audio should stop as well.

I am using SDL to play audio and initially the audio playing would cause the UI to hang so I put it on a background thread. Now the UI does not hang but now if I click through different files the whole program will hang then crash and not start and stop each file. I think it might be because I am making an object for each click and it eats up memory? I am not sure as I am new to Qt and C++ development.

This is the header file for the Audio player.

```
#ifndef AUDIOPLAYER_H
#define AUDIOPLAYER_H
#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED

#include <iostream>
#include <QObject>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

struct AudioData
{
    Uint8* pos;
    Uint32 length;
};

class AudioPlayer : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        AudioPlayer(char * fileName);
        ~AudioPlayer();
    public slots:
        void process();
    signals:
        void finished();
        void error();
    private:
        char *fileName;
        static void callback(void* userdata, Uint8* stream, int streamLength);
};

#endif // AUDIOPLAYER_H
```

This is the audio player implementation. It takes a file during initialization and then plays it when process is called.

```
#include "audioplayer.h"

AudioPlayer::AudioPlayer(char *fileName)
{
    this->fileName = fileName;
}

AudioPlayer::~AudioPlayer()
{}

void AudioPlayer::process()
{
    if(SDL_AUDIO_PLAYING || SDL_AUDIO_PAUSED) SDL_CloseAudio();
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_AUDIO);
    SDL_AudioSpec wavSpec;
    Uint8* wavStart;
    Uint32 wavLength;

    if(SDL_LoadWAV(this->fileName, &wavSpec, &wavStart, &wavLength) == NULL)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << this->fileName
            << " could not be loaded as an audio file" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    AudioData audio;
    audio.pos = wavStart;
    audio.length = wavLength;

    wavSpec.callback = callback;
    wavSpec.userdata = &audio;

    SDL_AudioDeviceID device = SDL_OpenAudioDevice(NULL, 0, &wavSpec, NULL, SDL_AUDIO_ALLOW_ANY_CHANGE);
    if(device == 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    SDL_PauseAudioDevice(device, 0);

    while(audio.length > 0)
    {
        SDL_Delay(100);
    }

    SDL_CloseAudioDevice(device);
    SDL_FreeWAV(wavStart);
    SDL_Quit();
    emit finished();
    return;

}

void AudioPlayer::callback(void* userdata, Uint8* stream, int streamLength)
{
    AudioData* audio = (AudioData*) userdata;
    if(audio->length == 0) return;

    Uint32 length = (Uint32)streamLength;
    length = (length > audio->length ? audio->length : length);

    SDL_memcpy(stream, audio->pos, length);

    audio->pos += length;
    audio->length -= length;
}
```

Audio player is created and called in my main window in a slot for when an TreeView item is clicked.

```
void MainWindow::playSound(const QModelIndex& clickedItem)
{
    auto item = fileFilterModel->mapToSource(clickedItem);
    QStandardItem *qStandardItem = filemodel->itemFromIndex(item);
    TreeViewData data = qStandardItem->data().value<TreeViewData>();
    if(data.fileInfo.isFile())
    {
        string filePath = data.fileInfo.absoluteFilePath().toStdString();
        char* c = strcpy(new char[filePath.length() + 1], filePath.c_str());
        QThread* thread = new QThread();
        AudioPlayer *audioPlayer = new AudioPlayer(c);
        audioPlayer->moveToThread(thread);
        connect(thread, &QThread::started, audioPlayer, &AudioPlayer::process);
        connect(audioPlayer, &AudioPlayer::finished, thread, &QThread::quit);
        connect(audioPlayer, &AudioPlayer::finished, audioPlayer, &AudioPlayer::deleteLater);
        connect(thread, &QThread::finished, thread, &QThread::deleteLater);
        thread->start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Qt has QString to deal with char *, qDebug() for debug messages. How an audioPlayer instance is stopped when another is click?

Comment: AFAIK Qt has its own API for playing sounds which should be much better for the integration in your application. Moreover, I am not sure initializing the SDL again and again in multiple thread is fine nor thread-safe.

Comment: If you're already using Qt, why not go for [QtMultimedia](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmultimedia-module.html)?